# Calling Flask endpoint from Flutter app on Android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flask

I am trying to call a Flask endpoint, `/api/v1/test`, from my Flutter app on an Android emulator.

I am getting the following error: `"Connection closed while receiving data"`.

In the Flask log, however, I see: `127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2023 11:16:34] "GET /api/v1/test HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

I use the dio package to perform HTTP requests. This is my Dart code:

```dart
  static Future<dynamic> get(String endpoint) async {
    var url = buildUrl(endpoint);
    var response = await dio.get(url);
    var resp = jsonDecode(response.data);
    if (resp == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return resp;
  }

  static String buildUrl(String endpoint) {
    if (!kReleaseMode) {
      return "http://192.168.1.31:5000/api/v1/$endpoint";
    }
    return "";
  }
```

`192.168.1.31` is my IPv4 address.

I have this permission added to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And this is how I launch my Flask app:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I am able to access the endpoint directly in Chrome on the Android emulator and view the response. I am also able to call the endpoint from Postman on my host machine without issues.

I am new to app development so I am not exactly sure why the HTTP request always fails when called from my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After much pain these are my findings, hopefully they can aid other frustrated souls (I still experience intermittent dropped requests for some reason):

- Ensure Flask server returns correct response (triple check this via Android emulator browser)
- Android apps seem to disallow non HTTPS connections per default
- Using `ngrok` as a proxy to tunnel requests to local server works
- Android emulators cannot communicate directly with `http://localhost` on host machine, use `10.0.2.2:<port>` instead
- Try disabling certificate checks in your HTTP client to circumvent HTTPS restrictions (only for dev purposes)

```dart
  static DefaultHttpClientAdapter _createUnsecuredAdapter() {
    final adapter = DefaultHttpClientAdapter();
    adapter.onHttpClientCreate = (client) {
      // This line disables certificate verification on all platforms
      client.badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) => true;
      return client;
    };
    return adapter;
  }

  [...]

  var dio = Dio()..httpClientAdapter = _createUnsecuredAdapter();
```